# Jmter performance of website parallel users

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, recording, poc

I have a scenario like to checks the performance of a website. The script should cover the scenario described below.

4 parallel users will open the web page (each user will start 5 seconds after the previous user) and each user will execute the following flow 3 times:
Search for a product on the main page
look-up the product within the search results
if found, open the product's page (if not found start over with another search)
add the product to the cart
check the confirmation message that the product has been added successfully to the cart
Each time the user executes the flow, it should search for a different product (it is ok if different users search for the same products).

I have recorded script in jmeter, but in http request showing as [image]

pls provide suggestions

Answer (score 0):

- `4 parallel users will open the web page (each user will start 5 seconds after the previous user)` - [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configured like

  [image]
- `if found, open the product's page` - put the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers which are responsible for opening the product page and adding it to cart under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller)
- `check the confirmation message that the product has been added successfully to the cart` - take a look at [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)
- `Each time the user executes the flow, it should search for a different product` - take a look at [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)